# Given a SciPy discrete random variable distribution, how do I round a number to the closest value in that distribution?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, distribution

What I ultimately want to do is round the expected value of a discrete random variable distribution to a valid number in the distribution. For example if I am drawing evenly from the numbers [1, 5, 6], the expected value is 4 but I want to return the closest number to that (ie, 5).

```
from scipy.stats import *
xk = (1, 5, 6)
pk = np.ones(len(xk))/len(xk)
custom = rv_discrete(name='custom', values=(xk, pk))
print(custom.expect())   
# 4.0

def round_discrete(discrete_rv_dist, val):
    # do something here
    return answer

print(round_discrete(custom, custom.expect()))
# 5.0
```

I don't know apriori what distribution will be used (ie might not be integers, might be an unbounded distribution), so I'm really struggling to think of an algorithm that is sufficiently generic.